# How to replace the default ModelState error message in Asp.net MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file, resources, modelstate

I need to replace the model state resource (to another language).

I've seen some answers to the question above, but unfortunately I could'nt make it work.
Any detailed answer or example would be appriciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got It.

In ASP.NET MVC 2 RC, It is **PropertyValueInvalid**, not **InvalidPropertyValue**.

Answer (score 12):

I don't know about v2, but this works on v1:

1. Add a resource file in App_GlobalResources.
2. In the resource file you can define strings named `PropertyValueInvalid` and `PropertyValueRequired`.
3. On the Application_Start global.asax event set `System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "resource file name"`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but for some reason it doesn't work.
Maybe there is a different way to do it on mvc 2.

Comment: You can find out using Reflector.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:     <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Price") %> without the star "*".

Comment: I consider this one the best approach. (+1). User messages belongs to Views, not to Controller. If in future you want to create the same page in another language, you will keep the same controllers and change ONLY the views.

Answer (score 1):

Cynthia, try to add this into your web.config

```
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".resx" type="System.Web.Compilation.ResXBuildProvider"/>
        <add extension=".resources" type="System.Web.Compilation.ResourcesBuildProvider"/>
      </buildProviders>
  </compilation>
```

MVC calls `httpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(ResourceClassKey, "InvalidPropertyValue", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)` to find the message, and sometimes you must add those providers to GetGlobalResourceObject find the correct resource