# Globally localize validation

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, attributes, data-annotations

I'm using System.ComponeneModel.DataAnnotations attributes such as Required and StringLength. Is it possible to localize its error messages globally?

I know I can do this

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Validation))]
```

But doing this everywhere I use required attribute would be just insane. Also I'd like to avoid stuff like:

```
public class LocalizedRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute {
    public LocalizedRequiredAttribute()
        : base() {
        ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required";
        ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Validation);
    }
}
```

(but if there isn't any other way, I'll settle for this)

Comment: Similar question with the same accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480557/providing-localized-error-messages-for-non-attributed-model-validation-in-asp-ne

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK you need either a custom attribute or specify the ErrorMessageResourceName and ErrorMessageResourceType properties. There is another possibility [detailed here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1512140/3608427.aspx):

> Create a global resource class in
>   App_GlobalResources, and set
>   DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey to
>   the name of this class (for example,
>   if you made "Messages.resx", then set
>   ResourceClassKey to "Messages").
>
> There are two strings you can override
>   in MVC 2:
>
> - The string value for
>     "PropertyValueInvalid" is used when
>     the data the user entered isn't
>     compatible with the data type (for
>     example, typing in "abc" for an
>     integer field). The default message
>     for this is: "The value '{0}' is not
>     valid for {1}."
> - The string value for
>     "PropertyValueRequired" is used when
>     the user did not enter any data for a
>     field which is not nullable (for
>     example, an integer field). The
>     default message for this is: "A value
>     is required."
>
> It's important to note
>   in the second case that, if you have
>   the
>   DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider
>   in your validator providers list
>   (which it is by default), then you
>   will never see this second message.
>   This provider sees non-optional fields
>   and adds an implied [Required]
>   attribute to them so that their
>   messages will be consistent with other
>   fields with explicit [Required]
>   attributes and to ensure that you get
>   client-side validation for required
>   fields.

Comment: Is it possible to replace these messages without using resource files? I need to intercept somewhere where these messages are generated and set localized error messages from DB. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For MVC3 see DataAnnotationsResources. It's "RequiredAttribute_ValidationError" and more.
You may solve it by installing .NET Framework language pack(s).

See also