# Localization for "the value {0} is invalid" in case of int overflow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, localization, validation

I've read [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5395297/291695) about localization of validation errors by specifying `DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey`, basically it's when entering string values in int field or not a datetime in datetime field.

But when I'm typing "111111111111111111111111111111" for an int field I get `System.OverflowException` and it looks like `"The value '{0}' is invalid."`.

Is there a way to localize (translate that message to other languages) that validation error in a way similar to other MVC-validation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, and I finally managed to find the solution. Yes, that message can be localized, and luckily it's pretty easy when you figure it out.

You have to create a resource file and put it in the `App_GlobalResources` folder. You can call the file whatever you want, but I usually call it MvcValidationMessages.

Open the resource file and create a string with the name `InvalidPropertyValue` and write whatever message you want in the value field.

Now, open the Global.asax file and add the following line to the method `Application_Start()`:

```
System.Web.Mvc.Html.ValidationExtensions.ResourceClassKey = "MvcValidationMessages";
```

"MvcValidationMessages" should of course be the correct name of the resource file you just created.

And voíla! That's all there is to it. The message shown will now be your own instead of the default one.

Comment: Just to point it out more loudly... `System.Web.Mvc.Html.ValidationExtensions.ResourceClassKey` is the trick. Thanks!

Comment: This did not work for me. I am trying to translate message: The value {0} is not valid for {1}. Should I really use InvalidPropertyValue key?

Comment: In my case, the correct was use DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey instead. And key inside the resx file was PropertyValueInvalid. Maybe, it is due to MVC version. Mine is 5.2.7

Answer (score 0):

I ended up overriding ModelBinder for `int` and supplying a localized error-message there:

```
public class IntModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        double parsedValue;
        if (double.TryParse(value.AttemptedValue, out parsedValue))
        {
            if ((parsedValue < int.MinValue || parsedValue > int.MaxValue))
            {
                var error = "LOCALIZED ERROR MESSAGE FOR FIELD '{0}' HERE!!!";
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, string.Format(error, value.AttemptedValue, bindingContext.ModelMetadata.DisplayName));
            }
        }
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Then I simply registered it: `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(int), new IntModelBinder());` and it now works fine.

P.S. sure, my localized errormessages are not hardcoded in model binder, this is just a simplified example :)