# MVC 5 - change Data anotation error message for Integers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations, unobtrusive-validation

In my Mvc5 test project I have a model with a property like the following:

```
[Required]
[DisplayName("Codigo Cliente")]
public int ClientCode{ get; set; }
```

the default error message when the user enteres a letter of special character in the editor is:

**The field Codigo Cliente must be a number.**

How can I modify this? in this case I need to change the language, but in case that I wanted to show a more specific error what can I do?

I have tried with the `DataType` attribute but the Enum does not have a value that applys for this case (numbers)

Comment: did you try to specifiy the message with [Required(ErrorMessage="Please ...")]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480557/providing-localized-error-messages-for-non-attributed-model-validation-in-asp-ne

Comment: @NicoD that would only show the error message if the user does not fill in a value in the editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Range:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute.aspx

Or use  **IntegerOnly** from **Data Annotations Extensions**

http://dataannotationsextensions.org/Integer/Create

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I found to solve this issue is use String with Range attribute  in Data Annotation Model  like specify below.

```
    [Required]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Codigo Cliente must be a positive or negative non-decimal number.")]
    [DisplayName("Codigo Cliente")]
    public string ClientCode { get; set; }
```

In Range attribute you can specify your custom Error Message. 
For Interger use int.MaxValue , For double use double.MaxValue like so on.
 I hope this will help you a lot.

Comment: iam sorry for downvote, it was my mistake, i cant take it back

Answer (score -1):

If you want to specify a message you must use this

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "your message")]
```

If you want to use a lang. based message is not that easy. You can use multiple resource file (for every language you need) and try a custom error binder that extends the DefaultModelBinder and make an override of the method BindModel(), there you can make your custom validation ad use your custom language message.

Comment: This would show the message when the user does not provide a value. what I want is to change the message when a user enters an invalid value. IE a letter in an editor that accepts integers

Comment: Using a custom error binder you can validate the value, read all the response.