# How can I change the error message for implicitly required properties in a view model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have properties declared in my view model like:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Date field is required for Start.")]
    [Display(Name = "Start")]
    public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }
```

However, I am still getting a default *The Start field is required* error message. I assume this is because a non-nullable `DateTime` is implicitly required, and the `Required` attribute is ignored. Is there a way to customise my error message for these specific properties, besides making them nullable?

Comment: possible dublicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214066/how-to-change-default-validation-error-message-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi That answer describes a global message change. I only want to change it for specific properties. I have updated the question.

Comment: no for specific values it is not possible to change it. However you can supply a format string with holes to be filled with the display nam of the field...se my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You right, your problem is that your property is not nullable. For not nullable properties attribute `Required` is meaningless. When there is no StartDate value, validation is not go to your `Required` attribute and fails on previous step. If you want to get your `ErrorMessage` you should 
use:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "The Date field is required for Start.")]
[Display(Name = "Start")]
public DateTime? DateStart { get; set; }
```

**You cannot customize ErrorMessage for nonullable types that get null on modelbinding, cause it is hardcoded deep in MVC framework.**

Comment: this is false!, see my answer belo and try it!

Comment: @Kirill, it seems you are right. This question has been open long enough, and I have been looking long enough, to conclude that using nullable view model properties is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've started with refresh new test project in MVC 4 and create a test model

```
    public class TestModel {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Date field is required for Start.")]
        [Display(Name = "Start")]
        public DateTime DateStart { get; set; }

    }
```

Then in my model I just have this:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.DateStart);
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.DateStart)
    <input type="submit" value="add"/>
}
```

When I remove clean the text box and hit submit, I am getting the customized error message instead of the default.

```
The Date field is required for Start.
```

This make sense to me, imagine if this is a multilingual application, you will definitely need to customize the error message for that country. It doesn't take a rocket scientist to realise the need for customized message. And I would expect MVC team have that covered.

Comment: @ProfK The exact message is "The Date field is required for Start." Let me know if you need a screenshot and the test solution I've create.