# How to change validation error messages in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I've been trying to change the validation error messages (in MVC3) and read a lot of threads and find out from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214066/how-to-change-default-validation-error-message-in-asp-net-mvc/6214961):

- Create App_GlobalResources folder for your project (right click to
  project -> Add -> Add ASP.NET folder -> App_GlobalResources).
- Add a resx file in that folder. Say MyNewResource.resx.
- Add resource key  PropertyValueInvalid with the desired message
  format (e.g. "content {0} is invalid for field {1}"). If you want to
  change PropertyValueRequired too add it as well.
- Add the code DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "MyNewResource" to
  your Global.asax startup code.

But I cannot make it work. Here is a clean MVC 3 web application I want to change the validation messages.  Please make it work for me as and as a sample for everybody else.

[here](http://www.4shared.com/zip/OX9jZHQJ/MvcApplication1.html?) is the link for my test project

Comment: take a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214066/how-to-change-default-validation-error-message-in-asp-net-mvc ..

Comment: I tried the approach in the link, and i put both of "RequiredAttribute_ValidationError" and "PropertyValueRequired" keys in the resource file, but nothing happened.

Comment: Please paste your Model/View/Controller in the query

Comment: is somebody gets it working for mvc 3 ?

Comment: I would like to see this answered as well.  I have followed the above steps and it is not working for me either.

Comment: still not working for mvc 5, anyone? :O/

Answer (score 0):

After some searching and trial and error, I used some code based on [this blog post](http://thatextramile.be/blog/2011/04/customizing-asp-net-mvcs-required-property-validation-messages/).  Adapted code below.

Add a new class to your project:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
public class FixedRequiredAttributeAdapter : RequiredAttributeAdapter
{
    public FixedRequiredAttributeAdapter (ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, RequiredAttribute attribute)
        : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
    }

    public override IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules()
    { 
        // set the error message here or use a resource file
        // access the original message with "ErrorMessage"
        var errorMessage = "Required field!":
        return new[] { new ModelClientValidationRequiredRule(errorMessage) };
    }
}
```

Tell MVC to use this adapter by changing app start in `global_asax`:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ...
        DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapterFactory(
            typeof(RequiredAttribute),
            (metadata, controllerContext, attribute) => new FixedRequiredAttributeAdapter(
                metadata,
                controllerContext,
                (RequiredAttribute)attribute));
```

There's more you could do with the error message such as getting from a resource file based on the class/property:

```
    var className = Metadata.ContainerType.Name;
    var propertyName = Metadata.PropertyName;
    var key = string.Format("{0}_{1}_required", className, propertyName);
```

Tested with MVC5.

---

**Update:** Looks like this only works for javascript/unobtrusive validation.  If you turn off javascript to get post-back validation, it still shows the "The {} field is required".

Comment: This doesn't work in ASP.NET Core (different method signatures). Is there some workaround?