# MVC 4 @html.validationmessagefor lengueje of result message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

[image]

The autogenerated text from the validation @html.validationmessagefor auto generates a text in english, i want this text to be in spanish, but whithout touch the data anotation of the property in the view model.

**Internationalization its not an option!
Data anotations nether!**

Comment: Not the response im looking for, internationalization its not the response!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19365233/2279977

Comment: Without data anotations! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution!

In the console http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference

First uninstall MVC 4 reference packages:

PM> **Uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc**

Then install MVC 4 package in spanish:

PM> **Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.es -Version 4.0.30506**

[image]
regards!

Answer (score 0):

I have used Resource files `(.RESX)` to extract the localized error message

```
public class BasicInfoViewModel 
{
 [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "REQ_FN", 
           ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Messages))]
 [StringLength(100)]
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Then In

Resources/Messages.resx file

REQ_FN -> `First Name Required`

Resources/Messages.(cultureCode).resx file

REQ_FN -> `Custure specific message for (First Name required)`

Comment: This is not a localization problem the problem is the lenguaje of the library generating the message...