# ASP.NET MVC - Default Validation Messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I've been "messing" around with the client side validation with ASP.NET MVC.

But the default messages are getting to me, I can't seem to overwrite some of them.

The only way I have found is to create resources in App_GlobalResources, like [How to change default validation error message in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214066/how-to-change-default-validation-error-message-in-asp-net-mvc)

However, the required string name doesn't seem to work, has it changed since MVC 2?

I've been trying to keep it as Embedded Resources, but ended up coming short with the Enums, as it checks if it's valid automatically, but the string isn't localized. So I might as well just use the Global_AppResources.

Global.asax

```
        DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey = "Global";
        ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey = "Global";
```

Part of model:

```
    [Display(Name = "TimeDisplay", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Models.Log))]
    [Required]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}")]
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
```

App_GlobalResources folder with Global.resx

```
PropertyValueRequired   Weeee
```

Comment: post your code here...

Comment: Just looked through reflection of DefaultModelBinder, and it is still that name alright, but it just doesnt seem to work