# Globally Override ASP.Net MVC Default Attribute Error Messages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

How can I use resources from a different assembly to override the default attribute error messages in my MVC5 application?

My website is namespaced: Company.Web

My resources assembly is namespaced: Company.Web.Resources

I can easily localize attribute error messages individually using:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "PropertyValueRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Company.Web.Resources.Messages))]
```

However, since our error message is always "Required", I'd simply like to put the `[Required]` attribute without having to specify the resource name. I'd also like to override the default data type messages output by MVC which you can't do via an attribute.

> The field {0} must be a date.

I'd like to be

> Invalid date

I've seen examples where you can put the resource files in App_GlobalResources (with keys `PropertyValueRequired`, `FieldMustBeDate`, `FieldMustBeNumeric`) and setting `ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey`, but I already have an external resources assembly I want to use.

I've tried using the following in my Global.asax with no luck:

```
ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider.ResourceClassKey = "Company.Web.Resources.Messages"
```

How can I accomplish this? Any ideas?

**UPDATE (Partial Resolution)**

I can solve my attribute-based problem simply by creating new validation adapters and using them in lieu of the default:

```
public class MyRequiredAttributeAdapter : RequiredAttributeAdapter
{
    public MyRequiredAttributeAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, RequiredAttribute attribute)
        : base(metadata, context, attribute)
    {
        if (attribute.ErrorMessage.IsNullOrWhitespace() 
            && attribute.ErrorMessageResourceName.IsNullOrWhitespace() 
            && attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType == null)
        {
            attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof (Resources.Validation.Messages);
            attribute.ErrorMessageResourceName = "PropertyValueRequired";
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(RequiredAttribute), typeof(MyRequiredAttributeAdapter));
```

However, this still leaves me scratching my head on how to override the default data type message for non-null properties such as DateTime and int. Also, I believe there are some I am unable to override because they are internal (DataTypeAttributeAdapter, CompareAttributeAdapter).

Comment: Couldn't you just create your own attributes inheriting the built in attributes?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately that doesn't handle the built-in data type validation for dates and numbers. For example, when you have a non-nullable DateTime property on a model (without using any attributes at all), the message output is "The field {0} must be a date.". I want it to say "Invalid Date".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change default validation error message in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214066/how-to-change-default-validation-error-message-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Not a duplicate. All those solutions rely on resources created within the same web assembly using App_GlobalResources. My resource strings need to derive from another assembly.

Comment: Did you manage to find a full solution to this? I have the same issue.

Comment: This works perfectly for `Required` attributes, but it does not work with `EmailAddress` attributes, because there is no `EmailAddressAttributeAdapter` to override.

Answer (score 1):

This might be quite late, but then here is a solution that should work based primarily on the logic behind your partial solution.

1. Implement a custom `RequiredAttribute` for your project

   ```
   public class MyRequiredAttribute : RequiredAttribute
   {
       //Your custom code
   }
   ```
2. Modify your `MyRequiredAttributeAdapter` code as shown. Notice that you now need to inherit from the generic `DataAnnotationsModelValidator` class, which allows you pass in your custom `MyRequiredAttribute`

   ```
   public class MyRequiredAttributeAdapter : DataAnnotationsModelValidator<MyRequiredAttribute>
   {
       public MyRequiredAttributeAdapter(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context, MyRequiredAttribute attribute)
           : base(metadata, context, attribute)
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attribute.ErrorMessage)
               && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attribute.ErrorMessageResourceName)
               && attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType == null)
           {
               attribute.ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Validation.Messages);
               attribute.ErrorMessageResourceName = "PropertyValueRequired";
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Add this to Global.asax (modified from what you have in your partial solution)

   ```
   DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(MyRequiredAttribute), typeof(MyRequiredAttributeAdapter));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To override the default data type message for non-null properties such as DateTime and int,
implement an own `MyClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider` based on the MVC `ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider`.
Add that instance to `ModelValidatorProviders.Providers`, and removed the default one.

So, put this into Global.asax:

```
var clientDataTypeModelValidatorProviderIndex = ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.FindIndex(modelValidatorProvider => modelValidatorProvider is ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider);
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.RemoveAt(clientDataTypeModelValidatorProviderIndex);
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new MyClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider());
```

Tested with MVC 5