# Jquery validation localization

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, localization, unobtrusive-validation

I use jquery validate unobtrusive in the Asp.Net MVC 5 project. And validation works in English, but I want it in other language, Norwegian for instance.

I found `messages_no.js` here `https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/tree/master/src/localization` and included that js file after `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`. I can see in developer tools that it is included in page properly but error messages are still in English.

Am I missing something?

Comment: are you using Html helpers to generate the form controls?

Comment: Yes, I am using Html helpers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error messsage are retrieved from html attributes(`data-val-`) of controls.
Controls are generated server side (`Html.EditorFor`), using the `DataAnnotations` of the property.

So for example instead of

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

you should use resources (.resx files)

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resource), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required"]    
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Make sure `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` are set in the desired culture.

Comment: Thanks, it works! I have one more question. Is it possible to define that error message globally, so I don't have to specify it everywhere I need Required attribute.

Comment: you want every property on every viewmodel to be required?

Comment: I want to be able only to write [Requried] and that it automatically fetches it from Resources.Required. If it is possible...

Comment: To define that in only one place, like some global attribute override.

Comment: I found it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084212/globally-override-asp-net-mvc-default-attribute-error-messages