# ASP.NET WebApi Changing default parameter binding error message

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have action method defined as

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(SomeEnum? param)
{
   ...
}
```

If I pass some invalid value for param which is not convertible to Some Enum type I get this message:

```
The value 'xxx' is not valid for Nullable`1.
```

It is default message which I can get from ModelState. I would like to customize this message. I have found plenty of tips how to do it in ASP.NET MVC (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214066/how-to-change-default-validation-error-message-in-asp-net-mvc)) but nothing for WebAPI. Changing DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey does not work in WebAPI. I have also tried to solve problem by customizing ParameterBindingRule:

```
config.ParameterBindingRules.Insert(0, parameter =>
{
   if (!typeof (EnumType?).IsAssignableFrom(parameter.ParameterType))
      return parameter.BindAsError("Error message");

    return null;
});
```

Unfortunately this also doesn't work.

Comment: You can create a custom ExceptionFilter to achieve your porpose.

Comment: @AnkushJain I have defined global exception filter but it is not reached in this case. I think I have to create some kind of custom binder or validator.

Comment: it will work. May be you have not followed proper rules to implement it. Read this carefully http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
// in Application_Start 
ModelBinderConfig.TypeConversionErrorMessageProvider = (context, metadata, value) =>
{
    ...
}
```