# Override Message “the value {0} is invalid for {1}” in case of int in WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I have a variable name `CountryId`(Integer Type).
If user provides a `string` or any random input to `CountryId`, the In-built `DefaultBindingModel` in ASP.Net throws an error :

> ```
> The value '<script>gghghg</script>' is not valid for CountryId.
> ```

I want to override this message and provide my own text if the `ModelState` fails. I want a generic solution.

I've searched and tried many solutions, but they only worked for MVC applications, not `webAPI`.

```
public class IntegerModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (valueProviderResult == null)
        {
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        }
         int i;

        return !int.TryParse(valueProviderResult.AttemptedValue.ToString(), out i) ? new ValidationResult("Failed") : ValidationResult.Success;

    }
}
```

And in my WebAPI.config :

ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(int), new IntegerModelBinder());

Expected :

> The value is not valid for CountryId.

Result :

> ```
> The value '<script>gghghg</script>' is not valid for CountryId.
> ```

Comment: Dont use DefaultBindinModel in that case, also please throw in some code in thequestion

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I know that the message is more clear, but the requirement is that EndUser should not be able to see the input value.

Comment: @CodeNameJack I tried making my own BinderModel, but It doesn't work. I was making a resource file and added a field "PropertyValueInvalid   The value '{0}' is not valid for {1}.". But no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Web API

For Web API you can replace the `TypeConversionErrorMessageProvider` to provide a custom message.

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ModelBinderConfig.TypeConversionErrorMessageProvider = CustomTypeConversionErrorMessageProvider;

        // rest of init code
    }

    private string CustomTypeConversionErrorMessageProvider(HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata modelMetadata, object incomingValue)
    {
        return $"The value is not valid for {modelMetadata.PropertyName}";
    }
}
```

Note the full qualification of the `modelMetadata` parameter of `CustomTypeConversionErrorMessageProvider`; if you don't do this, then the `ModelMetadata` class of `System.Web.Mvc` is referenced (due to the default `using`s in `Global.asax.cs`), instead of the one in `System.Web.Http.Metadata`, and you get an error:-

```
Error   CS0123  No overload for 'CustomTypeConversionErrorMessageProvider' matches delegate 'ModelBinderErrorMessageProvider'
```

## MVC

For MVC, you can use the localization capability of MVC to replace those validation messages.

Basically, you create your own resource file, point MVC to that resource file using `DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey` and in that resource file, specify your own text for the `PropertyValueInvalid` key.

There is a guide on how to do this [here](https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2012/01/31/data-type-validation-and-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx/).

Comment: Thanx. I've already tried it but this works in MVC only, not working for WebAPI.

Comment: @AnuragMaheshwari, don't mind... I just saw your answer where you found it :)

Comment: Hi @Aleks , thanx for the answer, but I tried using your solution, and I'm facing an error " No overload for 'CustomTypeConversionErrorMessageProvider' matches delegate 'ModelBinderErrorMessageProvider' ". Kindly, provide me a solution for this.

Comment: I found the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26782311/11727639

Comment: Hi @AnuragMaheshwari, that's strange. Was the method you used in your answer working? (it's more or less the same thing). What version of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core are you using?

Comment: Hi @Aleks My solution is working fine. But I'm getting error in the below line : ModelBinderConfig.TypeConversionErrorMessageProvider = CustomTypeConversionErrorMessageProvider; And I'm using the version 5.2.3 of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core

Comment: Hi @AnuragMaheshwari, I worked it out, please see my edit. I hadn't seen the conflict with `System.Web.Mvc.ModelBinder` and had to run up a new empty project to test.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will helps you, and Option #3: Use a custom model binder could be to the point solution.

```
public class LocationModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
      ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        string key = bindingContext.ModelName;
        ValueProviderResult val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);
        if (val != null)
        {
            string s = val.AttemptedValue as string;
            if (s != null)
            {
                return Location.TryParse(s);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

now we need to wire up the model binder.

```
   public object  MyAction2(
        [ModelBinder(typeof(LocationModelBinder))]
        Location loc) // Use model binding to convert
    {
        // use loc...
    }
```

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2012/04/20/how-to-bind-to-custom-objects-in-action-signatures-in-mvcwebapi/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone! But I got the solution.
To Overrride this message for Int Validation in WebAPI, you just need to add the following snippet in **Application_Start** method in **Global.asax.cs**

```
ModelBinderConfig.TypeConversionErrorMessageProvider = (context, metadata, value) => {

            if (!typeof(int?).IsAssignableFrom(value.GetType()))
            {
                return "The Value is not valid for " + metadata.PropertyName;
            }
            return null;
        };
```