# MVC 5 model validation message not correctly displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, double, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-validation, validationmessage

I am coding an MVC 5 internet application and I have a question in regards to validation on a field in a view model.

Here is my view model field:

```
[Display(Name = "Latitude")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid latitude.")]
public double startupLatitude { get; set; }
```

Here is my view code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.startupLatitude, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.startupLatitude, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.startupLatitude, "" , new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

If I enter a value that is not a double, such as the following:

> Test

I am getting the following validation message displayed in the view:

> The value 'Test' is not valid for Latitude.

Instead of:

> Please enter a valid latitude.

Why is this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the html generated by the `@Html.EditorFor()` method

Comment: this behaviour is normal and valid because you are entering string whereas model property is of type double.

Comment: And the use of `Required` is pointless here because `double` must always have a value. It's only necessary if you have `double?` (nullable)

Answer (score 1):

Because the Required parameter check for not null and the data you have entered is a "String" where as it expects double

If you will keep the field blank then the error Message will be shown as "Please enter a valid latitude."

**Edit :**

**[Set Default/Replace Default Validation Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214066/how-to-change-default-validation-error-message-in-asp-net-mvc)**

Or

Try Using `Regular Expression` as well.

Comment: Can I modify the code some way so that the validation message will be the same for either a null entry or a string?

Comment: `DataType` does not contain a enum value for `Double`