# Custom ErrorMessage for model property is not displayed in production environment only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, production-environment, culture

I'm developping an ASP.NET MVC3 application.

I use `DataAnnotations` for some properties of my Models, with a custom error message if input is not correct.
However, it perfectly works when I run my app in localhost, but when I put it on my webserver (which is a shared web server), the error message is the one by default.

Here is an example :

```
[Required]
[Range(1d, 1000d, ErrorMessage = "My custom error message in French")]
public decimal Surface { get; set; }
```

When user type "abcde" in `Surface` field, I have the following error message :

> The field Surface must be a number.

However, it should display the specified ErrorMessage. This works in localhost but not on my webserver.

I tried to force culture in `web.config` as follow :

```
<globalization culture="fr-FR" uiCulture="fr-FR"/>
```

But this doesn't work.

How can I force the application to display the `ErrorMessage` ?
I can't modify anything on the web server which hosts my app, it's a personal project hosted on a local website hosting.

Thanks for your help

Comment: _abcde_ cannot be parsed to a decimal, so it displays that error. If you were to enter `0` or `1001` you should get the error associated with the range attribute.

Comment: Probably, but I'd like the custom error message be displayed each time an incorect input is set, "abcde", 1500, -400 or anything which is not is the given range. How could I achieve this ?

Comment: Check out my answer below to achieve this

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214066/how-to-change-default-validation-error-message-in-asp-net-mvc) might help. Also some extra information in [this blog](http://www.dotnet-programming.com/post/2012/01/17/Customizing-Error-Messages-in-AspNet-MVC.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As  Stephen Muecke wrote "abcde" cannot be parsed into a decimal so it shows the generic error that "The field Surface must be a number".

To make the error message as you custom message you need to check if the input is a number/decimal and you can do it with a regular expression. Change your code as follows

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$",ErrorMessage = "custom error in your language")]// add this extra line
[Range(1d, 1000d, ErrorMessage = "My custom error message in French")]
public decimal Surface { get; set; }
```

You need to add the following line

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$",ErrorMessage = "custom error in your language")]
```

which check via regular expression if it is a number, it will also check the decimal points if they are more than 2 like 2.002 then it will also give the error. You can look into regular expressions to build another expression which suits you the best.

Comment: This seems to works, thanks a lot ! I'm a little bit disappointed I have to add the RegularExpression tag, I hoped ``Range` could do the trick itself.
But I understand the explanation, so, well... Thanks a lot :-)