# Remove unwanted tags from ValidationMessage method

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, string, extension-methods, html-helper

What I'm trying to do is to override the ValidationMessage method to return just the translated validation message without any html. I've used Agility pack to get rid of Html, but the current issue is, the inner text is returning unwanted text. How could I filter this and just return the message itself?

```
 public static MvcHtmlString ValidationTranslatedMessage(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string modelName,
        Func<string, string> lang)
    {
        var s = htmlHelper.ValidationMessage(modelName).ToString();

        var h = new HtmlDocument();
        h.LoadHtml(s);
        s = h.DocumentNode.InnerText;
        s =lang(s);

        return htmlHelper.ValidationMessage(modelName,s);
    }
```

[image]

As shown above at the moment the `InnerText` is retuning *The value '50884.00asdasd' is not valid for Rent.*

And it should return *The value is not valid for Rent.*

Comment: Do you want this for all property error messages - i.e. always return _The value is not valid for <nameOfProperty>_?. If so you can do this by creating a resource file and add a resource key for `PropertyValueInvalid`. Refer [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214066/how-to-change-default-validation-error-message-in-asp-net-mvc)