# How to correctly catch exception raised by view or even controller in ASP.Net MVC 5 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception, asp.net-mvc-5

Ok, I am newbie in ASP.Net MVC 5 and working on a small `already existing` project so bear with me. I am finding it hard to understand/handle/decode exception raised in my code.

Here is the way the exception is getting handled in the project:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            Response.StatusCode = 500;    
            Response.StatusDescription = Constants.DISPLAYED_ERROR_MESSAGE_SHARED;

            if (filterContext.Exception.GetType() == typeof(ValidationException))
            { Response.StatusDescription += Constants.ADDITIONAL_DETAIL_ERROR_MESSAGE + filterContext.Exception.Message; }
            else
            { Response.StatusDescription += Constants.GENERIC_ERROR_MESSAGE; }
        }
    }
}

public static string DISPLAYED_ERROR_MESSAGE_SHARED = "We apologize for the inconvenience, but an error has occurred. <br />";
public static string GENERIC_ERROR_MESSAGE = "Please retry your previous action. If the issues persist, please contact the facility.";
public static string ADDITIONAL_DETAIL_ERROR_MESSAGE = "<br />Additional Details: ";
```

**Error.cshtml**

```
@model HandleErrorInfo
@{ 
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ErrorLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2 style="color:darkred">An Error Has Occurred</h2>
<div style="color:black; font-size:110%;">
    @Html.Raw(Constants.DISPLAYED_ERROR_MESSAGE_SHARED)
    <br />
    @Constants.GENERIC_ERROR_MESSAGE

    <br />

    @if (Model.Exception.GetType() == typeof(ValidationException))
    {
        <div style="font-size:90%;">
            @Html.Raw(Constants.ADDITIONAL_DETAIL_ERROR_MESSAGE)
            @Model.Exception.Message
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

After studying I got to know that now any exception raised in the controller will be caught in above method thus protecting me from redundant use of try catch in our code. Fair Enough.

**Issue** No matter what ever the exception is raised in my project. I always see below message in browser
[image]

**Debug Results**
Everytime an exception is raised the value of `filterContext.handled` comes out to be `true` and thus the code never enters inside the `onException` Logic and directly `Error.cshtml` view is rendered. Also, I have noticed that when I check the value of `filterContext.Exception`  I see the exact `reason/issue` for the exception.

**Question 1:** When an exception is raised and I can see during debugging that `filterContext.Exception` is telling me the exact issue then why I do not see it in my browser. Why do I have to debug all the time and check the Exeception by hovering my mouse on filterContext.

**Question 2:** Everytime I debug I find the filterContext.Exceptionhandled to be true. In what case it will be false?

**Question 3:** By mistake I added a HtmlHelper textbox for a property in a view. But the model associated with that view did not had that property. Now when I debug I can see that filterContext.Exception is telling me the exact issue. But as my `filterContext.Exception` already knows what mistake I did. Can't I display that in my UI rather than a generic message all the time.

**Question 4**
Apart from hovering over and getting to know my mistake/reason of exception, what benefit can I take from filterContet.Exception. Can't I somehow make my mistake visible in a `graceful manner` in UI atleast when code is `in development` and `not in production`.

**EDIT**
Global Asax

```
    public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        }
    }
```

And in the `Application_Start` method in **strong text**Global.asax.cs I have this line:

```
FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
```

Comment: It seems that your exeption is already hnadled by another action filter or something like that. Make sure that you don't use HandleErrorAttribute somewhere in your code base by registering it globally.

Comment: As I am a beginner its diffcult for me to comprehend things properly. But I have added the content of global.asax in edit section.

Comment: Let me know if I shall look for a particular keyword or soemthing in my code and remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExceptionHandled`property is set to `true` because there is already `ActionFilter` that set that before reaching your `OnException` method defined into your controller.

You can remove the global registration of `HandleErrorAttribute` from your **Global.asax.cs** file so when executing your `OnException` controller method the `ExceptionHandled` property will be `false` and you have to set it to `true` before you quit this method.

The correct solution to use I think is to create a new class let name it `CustomHandleErrorAttribute` that derives from `HandleErrorAttribute` and overrides the `OnException` method on that derived class.

After that you can change this line:

```
filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
```

to this line:

```
filters.Add(new CustomHandleErrorAttribute());
```

Comment: As of now, I commented out `filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());` and now when I debug the exception is not handled. so far so good. But inside the logic of onException what changes shall I make. Code flow does not go inside the `if` block of onException

Comment: I mean the `second if` block.

Comment: `(filterContext.Exception.GetType() == typeof(ValidationException)` for what type of exception above statement will be true

Comment: If your exception is of type or a derived type of `ValidationException`

Comment: Got it, Thanks.  :)

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark it as an "Accepted answer" :)

Comment: Ok, I am being too needy now. ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43575329/how-to-prevent-user-from-accessing-certain-url-directly-in-asp-net-mvc-5